# VS 2015 WCF service reference is not updating

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2015, service-reference

Currently I converted a solution VS2010 to VS2015 and conversion was successful. Now when I am updating existing WCF service and it's showing 'Service reference update complete'. But I am not getting any reference and also web config file is not updated.

Same issue is happening after deleting the service and adding again the service.

Is there any way to solve this problem? I would be obliged.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean solution, then build and than again update. It shou

Comment: I have already done this you mentioned. Still getting the problem.